# Ayuda Puerto COM y VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, programación-móvil, puertos

Hola a todos quisiera saber si existe algun forma de emular el puerto COM, tengo una aplicacion en VB.Net para mandar sms mediante un smartphone pero necesita de ese puerto y yo tengo una laptop que pues no lo tiene y no puedo realizar pruebas. Espero puedan responder y gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si utilizas un SMS Gateway o un servicio como Twilio, Plivo?

Comment: Si es lo que queria hacer desde un principio pero en el trabajo me pidieron usar el movil como modem y pues no me queda de otra.

Comment: Si vas a usar el móvil conectado, no veo el sentido de usar el puerto COM.

Answer (score 1):

Solo instala los drivers de tu smartphone y Windows lo reconocera como Modem y le asignara un puerto COM.
Luego ya en el visual Studio agregar un control SerialPort y lo configuras con el puerto COM de tu smartphone.